# Display Date on Years Only PGSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this SQL query, and I want to display only the years. How can I do it? I'm getting years, months, days, and hours. Thank you.

```
SELECT date_of_birth, AGE(now(), date_of_birth) AS age
FROM students
ORDER BY age DESC
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `extract()`:

```
 select extract(year from AGE(now(), date_of_birth))
```